# Can't run GCC from command prompt even after adding path to the system's environment variable

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, gcc, environment-variables, mingw

**My problem:**

I installed MinGW tools on my windows computer and tried to run gcc from command prompt. I got the following error (in German):

```
Der Befehl "gcc" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

In English:

```
The command 'gcc' is either misspelled or could not be found.
```

**My question:**

Which sources of error do you recommend to take into consideration?

**What i did so far:**

So far, I followed advices that I found on the net and successfully completed the following steps:

1. I installed the `mingw32-base` package.
2. I identified the path: `C:\MinGW\bin`
3. I added the latter path to the system's path environment variable. I made sure to use the correct syntax (;).
4. I ran `echo %PATH%` and checked if the output contains `C:\MinGW\bin`.
5. I restarted my computer.
6. I closed all open command prompt windows and reopened `cmd`. I typed `gcc` again, but encountered the same error.

Note: I also installed Visual Studio Code on my machine, maybe that's a possible source of error?

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable expects semicolons (`;`) as separator, not colons (`:`). Can you check that? Maybe put the output of `echo %PATH%`  in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try move up mingw path after adding path to the system's path environment variable. Worked for me right now.
Like in this video (at 1:30)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozU20xxv3Ek

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).